# Multiple Audio Players on one page, only first player responds to click

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I took the audio player code from [this](https://blog.shahednasser.com/how-to-style-an-audio-element/) article, made a few style changes, and am now attempting to display multiple such players on one page. Currently, only the first player responds to clicks.

I used row and column elements to display full-page rows with 3 players per row, each player having its own icon image and audio source file. My trouble is now in establishing the index-searching procedure so that the JS can play audio_X when button_X is clicked.

I've tried other solutions on StackOverflow to no avail, so I've removed all the changes I tried and am starting again from square one.

```js
const playerButton = document.querySelector('.player-button'),
  audio = document.querySelector('audio'),
  playIcon = `
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#3D3132">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
      </svg>
          `,
  pauseIcon = `
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#3D3132">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zM7 8a1 1 0 012 0v4a1 1 0 11-2 0V8zm5-1a1 1 0 00-1 1v4a1 1 0 102 0V8a1 1 0 00-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
          `;

function toggleAudio() {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    playerButton.innerHTML = pauseIcon;
    //  document.getElementById("1").style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    playerButton.innerHTML = playIcon;
    //      document.getElementById("1").style.opacity = "0";

  }
}
playerButton.addEventListener('click', toggleAudio);

function audioEnded() {
  playerButton.innerHTML = playIcon;
}

audio.onended = audioEnded;

const timeline = document.querySelector('.timeline');


function changeTimelinePosition() {
  const percentagePosition = (100 * audio.currentTime) / audio.duration;
  timeline.style.backgroundSize = `${percentagePosition}% 100%`;
  timeline.value = percentagePosition;
}

audio.ontimeupdate = changeTimelinePosition;

function changeSeek() {
  const time = (timeline.value * audio.duration) / 100;
  audio.currentTime = time;
}

timeline.addEventListener('change', changeSeek);


const soundButton = document.querySelector('.sound-button'),
  soundIcon = `
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#3D3132">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.383 3.076A1 1 0 0110 4v12a1 1 0 01-1.707.707L4.586 13H2a1 1 0 01-1-1V8a1 1 0 011-1h2.586l3.707-3.707a1 1 0 011.09-.217zM14.657 2.929a1 1 0 011.414 0A9.972 9.972 0 0119 10a9.972 9.972 0 01-2.929 7.071 1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414A7.971 7.971 0 0017 10c0-2.21-.894-4.208-2.343-5.657a1 1 0 010-1.414zm-2.829 2.828a1 1 0 011.415 0A5.983 5.983 0 0115 10a5.984 5.984 0 01-1.757 4.243 1 1 0 01-1.415-1.415A3.984 3.984 0 0013 10a3.983 3.983 0 00-1.172-2.828 1 1 0 010-1.415z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>`,
  muteIcon = `
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#3D3132">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.383 3.076A1 1 0 0110 4v12a1 1 0 01-1.707.707L4.586 13H2a1 1 0 01-1-1V8a1 1 0 011-1h2.586l3.707-3.707a1 1 0 011.09-.217zM12.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L15 8.586l1.293-1.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L16.414 10l1.293 1.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L15 11.414l-1.293 1.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L13.586 10l-1.293-1.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>`;

function toggleSound() {
  audio.muted = !audio.muted;
  soundButton.innerHTML = audio.muted ? muteIcon : soundIcon;
}

soundButton.addEventListener('click', toggleSound);
```

```html
<div class="audio-player left">

  <div class="icon-container">

    <img src="coverart1.jpg" style="width: 100%" alt="">
    <!--<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="audio-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
             <path d="blahblahblahpath" />
        </svg>-->
    <audio src="audio/1.mp3"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="player-button">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#3D3132">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="blahblahblahpath" />
    </svg>
        </button>
    <input type="range" class="timeline" max="100" value="0">
    <button class="sound-button">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#3D3132">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="blahblahblahpath" clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this structure, I'm not quite sure how to index/search for specific players (beyond knowing that i should probably use queryselectALL and add for loops to some JS functions).

Any fixes? Currently the first player works perfectly, but no other player responds to clicks. Something with the event listener perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> beyond knowing that i should probably use queryselectALL and add for loops to some JS functions

That's the point: you'll need to assign event listeners to each player instance.

```js
let audioPlayers = document.querySelectorAll(".audio-player");

if (audioPlayers.length) {
  audioPlayers.forEach(function(audioPlayer, i) {
    let audio = audioPlayer.querySelector("audio");
    let playerButton = audioPlayer.querySelector(".player-button");
    playerButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      let current = e.currentTarget;
      let audio = current.closest(".audio-player").querySelector("audio");
      let btnSvg = current.querySelector(".useBtn");
      if (!audio.paused) {
        btnSvg.setAttribute("href", "#icon-play");
        audio.pause();
      } else {
        btnSvg.setAttribute("href", "#icon-pause");
        audio.play();
      }
    });

    let timeline = audioPlayer.querySelector('.timeline');
    timeline.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      let time = (timeline.value * audio.duration) / 100;
      audio.currentTime = time;
    });

    audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
      console.log('audio finished');
      timeline.value = 0;
    });

    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
      let percentagePosition = (100 * audio.currentTime) / audio.duration;
      timeline.value = percentagePosition;
    });
  });
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
}

.player-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -0.15em;
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-player left">
  <div class="icon-container">
    <audio preload="metadata" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/Kishi_Bashi_-_It_All_Began_With_a_Burst.mp3"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="player-button">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#3D3132">
        <use class="useBtn" href="#icon-play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <input type="range" class="timeline" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="audio-player left">
  <div class="icon-container">
    <audio preload="metadata" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/Kishi_Bashi_-_It_All_Began_With_a_Burst.mp3"></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="player-button">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#3D3132">
        <use class="useBtn" href="#icon-play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <input type="range" class="timeline" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  </div>
</div>

<svg class="plyrBtns" style="display:none" aria-hidden="true">
  <symbol class="icon icon-play" id="icon-play" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zM9.555 7.168A1 1 0 008 8v4a1 1 0 001.555.832l3-2a1 1 0 000-1.664l-3-2z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol class="icon icon-pause" id="icon-pause" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zM7 8a1 1 0 012 0v4a1 1 0 11-2 0V8zm5-1a1 1 0 00-1 1v4a1 1 0 102 0V8a1 1 0 00-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi @herrstrietzel, I'm trying to implement something similar on my website (linked), as far as I can tell everything has event listeners but still only the first audio player works. [link](https://jsomerset.uk)